# WORLDWIND : How to Draw line from one coordinate to another using degree minutes and meters

Tags: worldwind

i want to draw a line using only degree minutes, and one coordinate.
code something like this

`Line line=new Line();
line.setStartCoordinate(xx.xxx,xxx.xx);
line.drawTo(meters,degree,minutes);`

Comment: Are you want to draw line with an origin position, an radius in meter and an angle? If yes what is your angle coordinate? Trigonometric coordinates or compass like coordinate?

Answer (score 1):

To draw a line on worldwind one option is using [gov.nasa.worldwind.render.Path](https://worldwind.arc.nasa.gov/java/latest/javadoc/gov/nasa/worldwind/render/Path.html). To draw line you should provide list of [Positions](https://worldwind.arc.nasa.gov/java/latest/javadoc/gov/nasa/worldwind/geom/Position.html). Your start position could be first position. To provide second position in your case you could use some useful methods of Position class such as: [Position.greatCircleEndPosition()](https://worldwind.arc.nasa.gov/java/latest/javadoc/gov/nasa/worldwind/geom/LatLon.html#greatCircleEndPosition-gov.nasa.worldwind.geom.LatLon-gov.nasa.worldwind.geom.Angle-gov.nasa.worldwind.geom.Angle-).